# How to get the default iOS browser name?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, browser, ios7

The Stack Overflow app detects the name of my jailbrokenly-set default browser (Chrome). How can I achieve the same thing in objective-c and swift?

(Just the name, not the ActivityView code)

Example:

[image: chrome]

---

**Update:** I went into Settings > Stack Exchange and found this:

[image: settings]

It looks like the app defaults to Safari, but **iff** Chrome is installed then links will be sent to that browser. Chrome is most likely detected by the `canOpenUrl` method described in the answer below.

Comment: Does it detect that Chrome is your default browser or just that you have Chrome installed? i.e. Do you also have Safari installed even though it's not displayed?

Comment: @ndmeiri Yes, I have both installed, and a 3rd one too. Through jailbreaking I could change my default browser to Chrome so links from all apps open in Chrome for iOS. Somehow the Stack App found my current "default" browser.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect that the Stack Exchange app isn't checking for your *default* browser specifically. After all, since Apple doesn't provide an easy way to change your default browser, I doubt the SDK provides an API to detect the default browser.

Instead, the Stack Exchange app may use the `canOpenURL(_:)` method on `UIApplication` to test if a predetermined set of common browser apps are installed. For each browser that is installed, the action sheet gets a new button. That approach could resemble the following code snippet.

```
let safariURL = NSURL(string: "http://stackoverflow.com")!
let chromeURL = NSURL(string: "googlechrome://stackoverflow.com")!
let operaURL  = NSURL(string: "opera-http://stackoverflow.com")!

let sharedApplication = UIApplication.sharedApplication() // convenience

if sharedApplication.canOpenURL(safariURL) {
    // add "Safari" button to action sheet
}

if sharedApplication.canOpenURL(chromeURL) {
    // add "Chrome" button to action sheet
}

if sharedApplication.canOpenURL(operaURL) {
    // add "Opera" button to action sheet
}

// display action sheet
```

Comment: This is a reasonable approach, and good thinking, yet somehow even though I have Safari installed (can it be deleted?), Chrome shows up. Perhaps they use this approach and check Chrome first with fingers crossed?

Comment: @Drakes Perhaps. One way to test that would be to keep Chrome installed, but make Safari your default browser again. If the button still says Chrome, then you're right.

Comment: I switched back to Safari, and it still showed Chrome. I switched to another browser, and it still showed Chrome. I deleted Chrome, and it showed Safari.

Comment: I found some new info. See the edit to my answer. Your solution is probably what SE did. Thanks for the response.

Comment: @Drakes Okay, so we were right. It must just check to see if certain browsers are installed and then set the button title to the first found browser in the list. And you're welcome. I'm glad I could help.