# iOS 15: Open URL in Safari instead of default browser

Tags: ios, swift, safari, mdm

We are using MDM profile that should be installed via browser.
We open url with `UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler:nil)`.
If Safari or Chrome are selected as Default browser it works ok (profile is downloaded to Settings and ready for install).

The problem is if user has Firefox browser. Firefox downloads profile to downloads folder and thats it.

Is there any chance to force/choose with which browser would you like to try open URL?

Have you any other suggestions how to handle this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Hope this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44963668/choose-browser-while-clicking-url-in-uitextview

Comment: @son thanks. This works great if you want to check if specific browser exist on device and open for specific browser other than Safari. 
But it doesn't exist something like `URL(string: "safari://www.stackoverflow.com")` to open direct in safari.

If user have default browser set to something different than Safari this `UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler:nil)` open in default browser and not in Safari.